# Как из массива объектов сделать объект?

Tags: javascript

Массив примерно из 5-6 тысяч значений, хотелось бы как то оптимизацию еще учесть

Ключ `id` всегда уникальный

```
let objArr = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Test2', },
  { id: 3, name: 'Test3', },
  { id: 5, name: 'Test5', },
  { id: 6, name: 'Test6', },
];
```

Из массива объектов сделать объект где значение id сделать ключом

```
let obj = {
  2: { id: 2, name: 'Test2', },
  3: { id: 3, name: 'Test3', },
  5: { id: 5, name: 'Test5', },
  6: { id: 6, name: 'Test6', },
};
```

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. Подробнее [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `reduce` в помощь. Разбирайтесь и приходите, если появятся конкретные вопросы

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar
, ни `map` ни `reduce` тут не подходят, так как они возвращают массив, а нужен объект

Comment: @kpushilin Метод reduce() возвращает то, что захотите https://doka.guide/js/array-reduce/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня получилось решить через `Object.Assign`:

```
let objArr = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Test2', },
  { id: 3, name: 'Test3', },
  { id: 5, name: 'Test5', },
  { id: 6, name: 'Test6', },
];

Object.assign({}, ...objArr.map(n => ({ [n.id]: n })))

// {
//   2: {id: 2, name: "Test2"}, 
//   3: {id: 3, name: "Test3"}, 
//   5: {id: 5, name: "Test5"}, 
//   6: {id: 6, name: "Test6"}
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как из массива объектов сделать объект?

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
let arr = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Test2', },
  { id: 3, name: 'Test3', },
  { id: 5, name: 'Test5', },
  { id: 6, name: 'Test6', },
];

const obj = arr.reduce((o, v) => (o[v.id] = v, o), {})
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот несколько вариантов которые мне удалось придумать.

### Вариант 1

Самый очевидный (имо) способ:

```js
const objArr = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Test2', },
  { id: 3, name: 'Test3', },
  { id: 5, name: 'Test5', },
  { id: 6, name: 'Test6', }
]

const resultObj = convertToObj(objArr)

console.log(resultObj)

function convertToObj(arr) {
  const result = {}

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const arrItem = arr[i]
    const itemId = arrItem.id

    result[itemId] = arrItem
  }

  return result
}
```

### Вариант 2

```js
const objArr = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Test2', },
  { id: 3, name: 'Test3', },
  { id: 5, name: 'Test5', },
  { id: 6, name: 'Test6', }
]

const resultObj = convertToObj(objArr)

console.log(resultObj)

function convertToObj(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, elem) => ({ ...acc, [elem.id]: elem }), {}) 
}
```

### Вариант 3

```js
const objArr = [
  { id: 2, name: 'Test2', },
  { id: 3, name: 'Test3', },
  { id: 5, name: 'Test5', },
  { id: 6, name: 'Test6', }
]

const resultObj = convertToObj(objArr)

console.log(resultObj)

function convertToObj(arr) {
  return Object.fromEntries(arr.map((elem) => [elem.id, elem]))
}
```